# Eclipse not working - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I've downloaded the latest Eclipse LUNA. The problem is that as I start it, it is not showing up. The title bar just says "Eclipse" but does not show any menu list buttons.

Eclipse started but is not displayed. I've been following [these](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/) instructions.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You could try to run eclipse through the terminal - do see if any errors are printed.. Simply use the terminal to navigate to the folder you've downloaded and then run './eclipse'.

Answer (score 0):

you may try udtc (Ubuntu Developer Tools Center)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:didrocks/ubuntu-developer-tools-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-developer-tools-center

udtc ide eclipse
```

udtc will install eclipse luna.

For more information: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/ubuntu-developer-tools-center-01.html

**NOTE:**

As of Mar, 1st 2015, the PPA at didirocks has been deprecated (see [here](https://launchpad.net/~didrocks/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-developer-tools-center)) fortunately there is an alternative mentioned, namely:  [ubuntu-make](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make)

to use ubuntu-make instead, replace the first command line mentioned with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
```